# Why does this xmlHttpRequest fail>?

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/FarqA/

`ajax_info.txt` is a valid file on my computer. The error returns as thus:

```
Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR DOM Exception 11
```

Comment: On your computer, or on your server? If the script is at http://`www.example.com/path/to/script.here`, `ajax_info.txt` should be at `http://www.example.com/path/to/ajax_info.txt`

Comment: On my computer. I know jsfiddle does not have a path of ajax_info.txt but I'm just posting this to show you the problem I'm having. `ajax_info.txt` refers to `ajax_info.txt` on my computer. And it brings up that error.

Comment: So your server is requesting a file from your computer?

Comment: No. I'm not using a server. Just some client-side JS with an ajax request. I'm just practicing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many browsers will refuse to load local files through an `XMLHttpRequest` as a security measure. AJAX requests are restricted by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), but as the linked Wikipedia page notes,

> The behavior of same-origin checks and related mechanisms is not well-defined in a number of corner cases, such as for protocols that do not have a clearly defined host name or port associated with their URLs (file:, data:, etc.).

Loading a local file, even with a relative URL, is the same as loading a file with the `file:` protocol. Many web browsers restrict this, with good reason - imagine running a malicious HTML file on your local machine that could load any file on your computer and post its contents to a remote server.

So my guess is that the problem is that you're trying to load a local file. Try serving your script on a local or remote webserver and see if that fixes the problem. (If you have Python installed, you can go to the directory in question and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`, then go to http://localhost:8000/ in your browser).

Answer (score 1):

In your script each call too `HTTPRequest()` is creating a new request object, so the request with the `onReadystateChange` handler is never getting sent and request that is sent has no handler function. Here's an updated version of your fiddle that should work: http://jsfiddle.net/HwYUS/